# File not found exception using Linq

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm getting a strange runtime exception trying to execute a method that uses Linq. Here's the code:

```
public async Task<Cat> GetCat(int id)
    {

        string file = await FileReader.ReadFile("../Mocks/Data/Mock_Cats.json");

        List<Cat> cats = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cat>>(file);

        var cat = cats.Where(p => p.CatID == id).First();

        return cat;

    }
```

And here's the exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

What's strange about this is that the exception only occurs if I try to use the Linq expression. I have other methods in the same class not using Linq that run just fine.

I've tried installing System.Linq in the project to no avail.

Comment: Does your project reference the same version of the .NET framework as the System.Linq assembly you're referencing (.NET 4.0, from the looks of it)?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work unfortunately. One thing I'm having a hard time understanding is exactly which version is getting referenced. At this point I've removed all references to System.Linq, System.Core, and System but the code still compiles with "using System.Linq" in the class file.

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings, try setting your "Target Framework" under the *Application* tab to the same version as that assembly.